# keyboard browser shortcuts doesn't work in Silverlight if some control is selected

Tags: silverlight

In SilverLight application when a textbox or button has the focus if the users press the keyboard shortcuts: Ctrl + y Ctrl + to get the zoom browser this funcionallity doesn't work. Is there any workaround?

Huge thanks
Javier

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard support in SL is limited. See the following for more information:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015(VS.95).aspx
- http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=silverlight%20keyboard%20support&lang=en-GB